# Conjoining different (opposite) meanings in French

Tags: choix-de-mot, conjonctions, coordination

I have found on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19818/during-or-while-before-an-ing-word) a French phrase: “Mesures pendant et après forage”.

It puzzles me for I don’t know whether French allows to conjoin different (opposite) meanings.

I’d rather use the disjunctive conjunction “or”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider this as a shortcut for the whole (quite redundant) expression :

> Mesures pendant forage et mesures après forage

But, granted, each single measurement is made during OR after the drilling, and that's an exclusive one.

Like saying *un champ de fleurs bleues et blanches*, which of course doesn't imply two-colored flowers.

Comment: Thank you so much. +1 that you understand what I mean and answer perfectly my question, duly noted.

Answer (score 5):

It means measurements made both during and after the drilling.  If you replace *et* by *ou* it would have meant measurement made either during or after the drilling.